# How to get position of the clicked item in Flexbox Layout in android?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am using Android [Flexbox Layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout). I have managed to add custom views to the layout from a list and setting click listeners to each item. But the problem is getting the position of the clicked item. I am sharing my current code here.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnClickListener{

FlexboxLayout fLayout;
final ArrayList<String> strList  = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    for (int i=0 ;i<30; i++){
        strList.add("Item "+i);
    }

    fLayout = (FlexboxLayout)findViewById(R.id.flexLayout);


    for(int i=0;i<strList.size();i++){
          addView(strList.get(i),i);
    }

    fab.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.fab:
            addItem();
            break;
    }

}

private void addItem(){
    strList.add("Item "+ (strList.size()));
    addView(strList.get(strList.size()-1),strList.size()-1);
}


private void addView(String string, int pos){
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View item = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.flow_layout_item, fLayout, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(string);
    Button btn = (Button) item.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
    FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams) item.getLayoutParams();
    item.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    item.setClickable(false);


    /*Here I set click listener for button in custom view*/
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    fLayout.addView(item);
}


}
```

How can I get the position of the clicked items? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was achieved following the answer of @moyheen
I used RecyclerView with FlexBoxLayoutManager.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) 
context.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(context);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not entirely sure of how to get the position of clicked items through your current method, I know this can be easily achieved when using the `FlexboxLayout` with a `RecyclerView`.

You will be able to get the position from the `RecyclerView` adapter's `onBindViewHolder()` method.